# Python: how to know how many colors in a bounding box in PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, bounding-box

Hey, I've got so many PIL bounding box(x,y, x1,y1)

I just want to know how many colors are there in the bounding box, is there any fast way to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> myimg = ...
>>> colors = myimg.crop((x0, y0, x1, y1)).getcolors()
```

According to [PIL's docs](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) getcolors "Returns an unsorted list of (count, color) tuples, where the count is the number of times the corresponding color occurs in the image".

Comment: +1 for `crop()`, which is lazy, so, paradoxically, very fast.